# チュートリアルのheightAnchor.constraintとwidthAnchor.constraintについて

Tags: swift, xcode

swift公式のチュートリアルを進めていますが、一向に解決できない部分があるので質問させていただきます。
以下のURLに書かれているように、UIButtonを作るチュートリアルです。

[Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift): Implement a Custom Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1)

以下が私の書いているソースコードですが、Runすると通常赤い正方形のボタンが表示されるところが、長方形のボタンになってしまいます。

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIStackView {

//MARK: -Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        //プログラムでviewを初期化
        //frameがinitializer、スーパークラスの初期化子

        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButtons()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder){
        //storyboardでviewをロードできるようにする
        //coderがinitializer、スーパークラスの初期化子

        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupButtons()
    }

    //MARK: -Private Methods

    private func setupButtons() {
        let button = UIButton()

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        //ボタンの色

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //厳密には必要ないが、Auto Layoutを使う時は自動生成された制約を無効にしておくほうが良い
        //stackviewにviewを追加すると自動的にfalseになっている

        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        //ボタンの高さと幅の制約を決める

        addArrangedSubview(button)
        //ボタンを表示させる
    }

}
```

UIStackViewのサブクラス（Rating Control)を作成し、storyboardの方でhorizontal Stack Viewと接続しています。
おそらく

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
```

の部分に問題があると考えていますが、どうなのでしょうか…。
他サイトでほとんど同じような質問がされていても回答がなかったり、海外サイトでの質問と回答も試しましたがダメでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結論から言うと、

**チュートリアルの表示例が間違っている**

と言うことです。そこまでのチュートリアルを順に進めて、説明にあるようにコードを記載していくと、あなたのご質問にあるような表示になります。チュートリアルの表示例は間違いです。

(あるいは、説明のどこにも書いていない何かをしないと同じ表示は実現できない…。)

---

そもそも、`UIStackView`と言うのは、「子ビューたちをうまく並べて親(`UIStackView`)全体をうまく埋める」ためのものです。それを実現するために、追加される子ビュー側に強力な制約(constraint)を付けていきます。設定によっては、そのために子ビュー側の元の制約(`button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true`とか)が無視されてしまうこともあります。

子ビューが1個だけだと、それ1個だけで親ビュー全体を埋めようとしますから、あなたの画面のような表示になります。

---

とりあえず、現時点のコードに最小限の変更を施してチュートリアルの表示例のような画面を作りたければ、次のようにして見てください。

```
    private func setupButtons() {
        //...

        addArrangedSubview(button)
        //ボタンを表示させる

        let filler = UIView(frame: .zero) //<-
        addArrangedSubview(filler)        //<-
    }
```

---

残念ながら、このチュートリアル、Apple製の公式のものであるにも関わらず、この手の破綻がちょくちょく報告されています。(章の後半、かなり先の方のコードを記載しないと表示例が間違っているどころかビルドが通らず、画面の確認自体ができない、とか。)

一部は直されていっていると思うのですが、まだまだ100%信頼しても大丈夫と言う状態ではないようです。章の途中の表示例が違う程度の場合、「また出たか」くらいの気持ちで先に進んでみてください。それでもダメでも、あまり長時間悩まずにここなんかに質問してもらった方が良いでしょう…。

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます。なるほど、やはり公式のチュートリアルでも間違っていることがあるのですね。それが分かって良かったです。色々試してもチュートリアルと同じ表示にはならなかったので、何となくおかしいなとは思っていました。次回からあまり悩みすぎないようにします。

Comment: ちなみに追加なさったコードは、SubViewに何を施しているのでしょうか…？

Comment: @AyanaMatsumoto さん、「子ビューが1個しかない時にその子ビューを画面いっぱいに広げようとする」のが今回見られた挙動の原因ですので、大きさがゼロの中身が何にもないもう1個の子ビューを追加してます。これによって、(設定にもよるんですが)`UIStackView`に対して「1個の子ビューを目一杯広げるんはやめといて、2個ある子ビューの隙間のスペース広げて埋めよかな」なんて思わせているわけです。「大きさ0のビュー」に対する動作はiOSのバージョンアップで突然挙動が変わることもあるので、あまりお勧めできる方法とは言えないかもしれません。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございました。